# problem in geoserver rest api

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I want to user geoserver rest api in netbeans. i create new **Maven Web Application** project:

[image]

and then edit **pom.xml** like following:

add **repository**:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
     <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

add **dependency**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and then create new **index.jsp** file and then add to body tag following code:

```
<%
    String RESTURL  = "http://localhost:1234/geoserver/rest";
    String RESTUSER = "admin";
    String RESTPW   = "geoserver";
    GeoServerRESTReader reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
    GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(RESTURL, RESTUSER, RESTPW);
    boolean created = publisher.createWorkspace("myWorkspace");
%>
```

and then add to top of the file:

```
<%@ page import="it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTPublisher" %>
<%@ page import="it.geosolutions.geoserver.rest.GeoServerRESTReader"%>
```

when i run this file occur following:

[image]

***where is problem? how can i solve it?***

Answer (score 2):

For using geoserver-manager with Maven, follow this: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki#working-with-maven Looking at your post, you declare a dependency instead of a repository, and the log indicates that some class is not found, which may indicate geoserver-manager is not found on your classpath.

Check your `pom.xml` is valid, and that geoserver-manager was downloaded and is available in your project maven dependencies.

I would then suggest you first to familiarize with the geoserver-manager using a simple java program (no need for a web application here), start familiarizing with the examples provided here https://github.com/geosolutions-it/geoserver-manager/wiki/Various-Examples#some-examples It can be the one you pasted to create a workspace.